# studying the function $f(x)= \sqrt{x^2+x}-x$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying the function $$f(x)= \sqrt{x^2+x}-x$$
The domain is $(- \infty, -1] \cup [0, + \infty)$.

In particular I'm making some mistakes about the sign of the
first derivative $$ \frac{2x+1-2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}{2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}$$
The first derivative is never zero.

$ \frac{2x+1-2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}{2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}>0 \Rightarrow   2x+1-2 \sqrt{x^2+x} >0 \Rightarrow   2x+1>2 \sqrt{x^2+x}  \Rightarrow   1>0 $ . So it seems that the derivative is always positive in the domain.

But comparing with the result in wolfram alpha the function is decreasing in $(-\infty, -1]$

Comment: Really the inequality that gives you the sign of first derivative it is satisfied for $x>0$! Hint: be careful to not squared simply the last inequality: the LHS it is not necessary positive!

Comment: it is part of a hyperbola as $(x+y)^2= x^2+x$ Get some paper and draw a picture... In particular, it has two asymptotes (lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \frac{2x+1-2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}{2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}>0\iff 2x+1-2\sqrt{x^2+x}>0\iff 2x+1>2\sqrt{x^2+x}\iff \begin{cases}2x+1>0\\  x^2+x> 0\\ (2x+1)^2>4(x^2+x)\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}x>\frac{-1}{2}\\x> 0 \vee x< -1\\ \forall x \end{cases}\iff x> 0 $$ Be careful to exclude $0$ in order to have the denominator not equal to $0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the domain of the derivative
$$f^\prime(x)\:=\: \frac{2x+1}{2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}-1$$
is not equal to the domain of $f$ since the denominator zeros $\{-1,0\}\,$ have to be excluded.

The sign analysis is quickly achieved using the AGM inequality:
If $0<x$ then
$$\sqrt{x(x+1)}\:<\:\frac{2x+1}{2}\quad\implies\; 0\;<\;\frac{2x+1}{2 \sqrt{x^2+x}}-1$$
For $x<-1$ one obtains
$$\sqrt{(-x)(-(x+1))}\:<\:\frac{-x-(x+1)}2 \;=\; -\frac{2x+1}{2}\quad\implies\;
f^\prime(x)<-2$$